# MSK S3 connector in us-west-2 gives timeout error while connecting to S3 bucket in us-east-1

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, timeout, aws-msk, s3-kafka-connector

I have deployed MSK cluster and MSK S3 sink connector in `us-west-2`.

Sink bucket is in `us-east-1`.

When MSK connector starts up, it fails with timeout, waits for 25-30 minutes, retries, and fails over and over again.

Here are the logs (`my-sink-stg` is connector name):

```
[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]  (io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig:361)
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] [2023-07-17 05:49:33,870] INFO [my-sink-stg|task-0] Returning new credentials provider based on the configured credentials provider class (io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage:173)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] [2023-07-17 05:54:55,056] ERROR [my-sink-stg|task-0] WorkerSinkTask{id=my-sink-stg-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception. Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:191)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3.amazonaws.com:443 [s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.209.88, s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.199.40, s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.170.48, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.40.110, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.228.224, s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.40.168, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.201.152, s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.89.29] failed: connect timed out"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.start(S3SinkTask.java:140)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:308)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:196)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:189)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:238)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] Caused by: com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to s3.amazonaws.com:443 [s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.209.88, s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.199.40, s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.170.48, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.40.110, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.228.224, s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.40.168, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.201.152, s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.89.29] failed: connect timed out"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1219)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1165)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:814)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:781)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:755)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:715)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:697)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:561)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:541)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5456)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:5403)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:4062)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:1278)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.getBucketAcl(AmazonS3Client.java:1268)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.doesBucketExistV2(AmazonS3Client.java:1406)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at io.confluent.connect.s3.storage.S3Storage.bucketExists(S3Storage.java:184)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.start(S3SinkTask.java:114)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     ... 9 more"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to s3.amazonaws.com:443 [s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.209.88, s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.199.40, s3.amazonaws.com/54.231.170.48, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.40.110, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.228.224, s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.40.168, s3.amazonaws.com/52.217.201.152, s3.amazonaws.com/52.216.89.29] failed: connect timed out"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:151)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor137.invoke(Unknown Source)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ClientConnectionManagerFactory$Handler.invoke(ClientConnectionManagerFactory.java:76)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.conn.$Proxy47.connect(Unknown Source)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.apache.client.impl.SdkHttpClient.execute(SdkHttpClient.java:72)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1346)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1157)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     ... 24 more"
[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:368)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at com.amazonaws.http.conn.ssl.SdkTLSSocketFactory.connectSocket(SdkTLSSocketFactory.java:142)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c]     ... 39 more"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] [2023-07-17 05:54:55,058] INFO [my-sink-stg|task-0] Metrics scheduler closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:668)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] [2023-07-17 05:54:55,058] INFO [my-sink-stg|task-0] Closing reporter org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.JmxReporter (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:672)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] [2023-07-17 05:54:55,059] INFO [my-sink-stg|task-0] Metrics reporters closed (org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.Metrics:678)"
"[Worker-0830298caeb23471c] [2023-07-17 05:54:55,060] INFO [my-sink-stg|task-0] App info kafka.consumer for connector-consumer-my-sink-stg-0 unregistered (org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser:83)"
```

Connector's role already has a permission policy for accessing the sink bucket:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*",
            "Sid": ""
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:AbortMultipartUpload"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-stg/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-stg"
            ],
            "Sid": ""
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Interestingly, connector runs fine if MSK cluster and MSK connector are in the same region as the sink bucket, i.e. `us-east-1`

Connector's security group has "allow all" for both inbound and outbound rules.

Anyone knows what could be causing this timeout issue?

UPD. Connector uses IAM authentication and has the following configs set:

```
"sasl.mechanism": "AWS_MSK_IAM",
"sasl.jaas.config": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMLoginModule required;",
"sasl.client.callback.handler.class": "software.amazon.msk.auth.iam.IAMClientCallbackHandler",
```

UPD2. Tried attaching internet gateway to connector's subnet, and updating route table to forward packets with S3-related IPs to that gateway. I am able to ping all IP addresses shown in the error logs, from EC2 instance launched in connector's VPC. Completely clueless now

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the region in the connector config. [See `s3.region`](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/s3-sink/current/configuration_options.html#s3). You may also need to modify `s3.credentials.provider.class`, in case the IAM policy isn't taking

Comment: I do set `s3.region` to `us-east-1` in the connector config. The cluster has been configured for IAM and SASL/SCRAM authentication. The connector uses IAM authentication and correspondingly IAM bootstrap servers. I pasted the IAM-related configs at the end of my original post

Comment: `s3.credentials.provider.class` uses `DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain` by default, is there a need to set it to something else? could you elaborate on `IAM policy isn't taking`, could not really understand what that means

Comment: I do not have experience with MSK Connect, only self-managed in EC2... Perhaps you can open a support ticket with MSK to help debug why a timeout would occur on their own network?

Comment: already opened : ))